# How to adjust margin the Text inside the button

Tags: android, android-xml

In my app i need to reduce the buton size if i did that the text of the button cannot displayed on that button. so how to align the text inside the button

this is my button.xml code

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/intro_button"
                android:layout_width="560dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="50dp"
                android:text="@string/Introduction"
                android:textSize="10dp"/>
```

this is String.xml code

```
<string name="Introduction"></string>
```

Comment: Use TextView instead of button.

Answer (score 1):

If you reduce the button size, you have reduce the padding too.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/intro_button"
        android:layout_width="560dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:text="Introduction"
        android:textSize="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TextView`,
set a `background` with some `padding`:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/intro_button"
android:layout_width="560dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="50dp"
android:text="@string/Introduction"
android:textSize="10dp"/>
```

Then, in your java file, find your textview using the id and set an OnClickListener on it

Answer (score 0):

Use this,
Depending on your Text and textSize Button will Create:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/intro_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="stringIntroduction"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding android:padding="50dp" also added space on the whole button , so i just wanted to add some extra space on the right/left so that text didn't overlap with the button layout:

```
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
```